# Securing Jenkins multibranch pipeline for open source projects

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, open-source, pull-request

### How to properly secure Jenkins multibranch pipeline for open source projects?

> I work on an open source projects, with community contributions made
>   using pull requests.  I want to build those PR, but if I do so, there
>   is a risk that those parts **get modified and host malicious code or
>   steal credentials** :
>
> - the pipeline
> - the pipeline's dependencies
> - the test suite
> - ...

---

For what it worth, I did researches, and my *beginner* point of view is this:

1/ Find a way to prevent modified code to be executed for :

- pipeline
- pipeline's dependencies

=> is it even possible?

2/ execute build only on agent never on master

3/ find a way to properly block agents to access secrets (like github/slack tokens)

4/ Find a way to mitigated what a malicious test code can do

- the agent's should use a subnet with only this agent and the master
- the agent should run on a separate VM/container

Answer (score 2):

2/ execute build only on agent never on master
:- Never use "Agent Any" instead use Agent labels on your pipeline. you can switch your node on pipeline execution by mentioning Agent at stage level.

3/ find a way to properly block agents to access secrets (like github/slack tokens)
:- Use **Credentials** method and declare it in environment section.

```
  environment {
      YOUR_PASSWORD = credentials('<CREDENTIAL_ID>')
  }
```

Comment: Thank you.  More on this: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Security+implication+of+building+on+master